# Shear stresses in a rectangular beam

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, structural-beam

[image: problem from Mechanics of Materials]

To find the shear stress at point A in the beam above using the equation τ=VQ/(It), how do you decide which value of thickness to use? Is it correct to use a value of 100 mm because the cut segment at A is 100 mm long , or 20 mm because the segment extends to both ends of the beam and so the shear stress at A acts at both ends of the beam?

Comment: When analyzing stresses at a discontinuity, it's good practice to identify the largest possible value, as this will bring the material closest to the point of failure. Further, note that point A isn't located within the 100-mm width region; it's located at the extreme end of the 20-mm width region.

Comment: When using an equation which you are not sure about, it is best to go back to the place where you got the equation from. Check what the symbols mean and what assumptions the equation makes.